# Logic App: Pass dynamic subscription id and resource group name in an ARM template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

Hey It's been days that I am trying to deploy my first logic app with dynamic resource group name and subscription id using Azure DevOps, I looked on several links that doing something like in my template.json file:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "workflows_app_name": {
            "defaultValue": "myLogicApp",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "connections_azuretables_externalid": {
            "value": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azuretables",
            "type": "String"
        }
....
```

tried this too:

```
 "connections_azuretables_externalid": {
            "defaultValue": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().id, '/resourceGroups/', resourceGroup().name, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azuretables')]",
            "type": "String"
        }
```

and this as well trying to pass resourcegroup name and subscription in paramters:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "workflows_app_name": {
            "defaultValue": "myLogicApp",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "connections_azuretables_externalid": {
            "defaultValue": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'), '/resourceGroups/', parameters('ressourceGroupName'), '/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azuretables')]",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "subscriptionId": {
          "type": "String"
        },
        "ressourceGroupName": {
          "type": "String"
        },
.....
}
```

but getting errors similar to this

> Property id '[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'), '/resourceGroups/', parameters('ressourceGroupName'), '/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azuretables')]' at path 'properties.parameters.$connections.value.azuretables.connectionId' is invalid. Expect fully qualified resource Id that start with '/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}' or '/providers/{resourceProviderNamespace}/'

I know I am missing or misunderstanding something but can't figure it out! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the API property in the properties section of template.json file like below and then refer the variable name in Library of DevOps

```
"api": {
         "id": "[concat(subscription().id,'/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/',variables('rgLocation'),'/managedApis/azureblob')]"
       }
```

In this case the storage location is Blob, you can customize it to storage of your choice

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the point is to not create a variable in Library, what I want is when deploying it will replace the current resource group name it's been deployed to like the subscription.id(), how can I achieve this as the links I found didn't work for me.

Comment: I doubt that is even possible directly because you have to specify the parameter value. Can you try adding a PowerShell code to your release pipeline so that the code will take the resource group / subscription id at runtime?

Comment: I don't know how to manipulate powershell code to take the resource group, can you add a reference how to do it pls? since It's my first time deploying ARM template

Comment: You can refer following links:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61679470/how-to-list-resource-groups-across-azure-subscriptions-using-powershell

2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresourcegroup#:~:text=The%20Get%2DAzResourceGroup%20cmdlet%20gets,groups%20in%20the%20current%20subscription.

You can use Login-AzureAzAccount to login via your credentials and get subscription details

Comment: Hi @marOne : If my response helped you, can you please mark it as an answer so that we can have others from community to benefit from it :). Thanks !

Comment: Hi @Pratik, just saw your comments, your refs work in local i guess, I m trying to deploy ARM template with Azure DevOps how can I use powershell commands ?

Answer (score 0):

> Logic App: Pass dynamic subscription id and resource group name in an ARM template

You could try to add Azure Cli task to get the subscription and create a pipeline variable called **subscriptionId**:

```
  jobs:
  - job: GetSubscription
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'CTP.AssuranceDW-Non-Production'
        scriptType: 'ps'
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: |
          $id = convertfrom-json (az account list --query "[?isDefault].id | [0]")
          Write-Host $id
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=subscriptionId]$id"
    - powershell: Write-Host $(subscriptionId)
```

Then, we could use the `overrideParameters` or replacetokens task to pass this value to the ARM template.

Please check the thread [How to pass an Azure pipeline variable to an ARM template used by AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62030687/how-to-pass-an-azure-pipeline-variable-to-an-arm-template-used-by-azureresourcem) for some more details.

Comment: Thanks Leo, I will try your solution ASAP